# Posted a question, then finshed registering. But the questions is not mine

Tags: discussion

I posted a question on this website (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions?page=2&sort=newest), and then I completed the registration afterwards from the email that was sent. However, the user that posted this question is still unregistered. How can I claim this questions as "mine"? I need that since I can not even comment on the replies on this questions.

Comment: Look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for help on getting your accounts merged.

Comment: Thank you! Dont understand why I need to do this though, I just followed exactly the instructions in the email, there should never have been two accounts created...

Comment: I'm afraid the registering process is something we don't have control over - it's inherited from the central Stack Exchange software.